# How do I populate a 'NewItem' form field automatically using a field from an item from another list

Tags: list, custom-form

I have two lists

1) List for the characterisation of a Product

2) List for the production of a Product after characterisation

For rudimentary access permissions reasons these need to be two seperate lists for my purposes.

I have a requirement to have an area in SP where a senior manager can view anything that's had it's characterisation completed and move items of interest into List 2 by way of a 'request'.  I have created a site page around list 1 that will fulfull this requirement (all through views of fields in list 1) that also has a column with a hyperlink to the 'new item' form for list 2 for the request.  This hyperlink is in the table alongside each individual item.

What I want is for the name of the product to be autopopulated from list 1 when you open the 'new item' form for list 2 through this hyperlink. Is there a way to do this using the solutions I already have above and staying within SP Designer (no added downloads)?  Is there potentially a better way to tackle this whole problem?

If there is a solution for this can it also be done without too much in depth manipulation of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [SPFF](http://spff.codeplex.com/) for this. It is a javascript library and allows you to set form fields based on the values in the query string e.g.
/Lists/Tasks/NewForm.aspx?Title=this is a test of text field

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need to stay within SP designer if possible.

Comment: You will stay inside the SP designer. Here is how you can do it. Add the SPFF Jquery library to any Document Library. Then Eidt the NewForm.aspx page of the second list. Add a Content Editor webpart (CEWP) to it and refer the js file like:<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/spff.js"></script>. Then add document ready instruction: $(function(){
 $.spff();
}); In the hperlink field of List 1 , append the link with query string : /Lists/Tasks/NewForm.aspx?Title=this is a test of text field

Comment: This works great, thanks.

Follow up question, instead of populating it with predefined text, how can I get it to prepopulate with the row from the field the link is on?

Comment: What do you mean by "Populating with the row"? Do you mean to send different field values using querystring and then using them to set fields in the target list. I don't think that is possible using SPFF. What I know about it is that it can be used to set single fields using query string. You may however like to see its documentation on codeplex.

Comment: The list that has the hyperlink on it also has a field called 'Product_Name'.  The Hyperlink is on the list for each item. I would like for the NewForm.aspx to autopupulate a field called 'Name' with the value of 'Product_Name' from the list item you select the hyperlink from. Is there a way to populate the url with the value from the list item using a querystring and this library?

Comment: If the Name field is a text field you can simply use this /Lists/Tasks/NewForm.aspx?Name=Value of Product_Name field.

Comment: Thanks. the Name field is a text field, however the value is different for each item so I can't just set it as text in the URL, or it just comes out as the same every time you click one of the hyperlinks. What I want is for when you click the hyperlink on the page (there is one for each item in the list) it calls the value of the Name field and prepopulates the Product_Name field on the form.

Comment: How are you adding the Url in hyperlink field?

Comment: In SPD I made a custom page for the list,adding a blank data view and then adding all the fields I wanted included one surplus as multiple item form.  I then changed the surplus field in the list into a hyperlink instead of a list form field using the Common FormField tasks and edited the hyperlink and pointed it at the newitem.aspx form from the second list.

Comment: Answering you just gave me inspiration, I've fixed it now, Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help!